# Why is my string limited to one word? (c++)

Tags: c++, string

In the following code the title and body are cut off after one word. I thought strings could hold several words? Could someone clear this up. Thanks

```
#include <fstream.h>  
#include <iostream.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string data, newtitle, body;

ofstream outfile;

int main()
{
   cout << "enter title of note: ";
   cin >> newtitle;

   cout << "enter body of note: ";
   cin >> body;

   data =  newtitle + ".dat";

   outfile.open(data.c_str(), ios::out);
                    outfile << body << endl;
   outfile.close();               

system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `std::string` can hold multiple words. `cin >> newtitle;` will stop scanning when it finds a white space character.

Comment: Rookie mistake blaming the string without considering that the way you're populating it may be at fault!

Answer (score 1):

`cin.operator>>` delimits on any whitespace (including spaces) by default.  You can use [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to get a whole line of input:

```
 cout << "enter title of note: ";
 getline(cin, newtitle);

 cout << "enter body of note: ";
 getline(cin, body);
```

Comment: The conversion from apstring to string was confusing me. Now my programming skills are back with the rest of the 21st century. Thanks